# Pre-populating document PDF form fields

Tags: docusignapi

This question related to the DocuSign API.  We are presently successfully sending documents to DocuSign.  The documents we are sending include a PDF with an interactive form.

What is the best way to pre-populate the fields on the interactive form?

A way that has occurred to us is to

1. Upload the document in draft status and let DocuSign process it
2. Request the custom fields from DocuSign
3. Make a request to modify the custom fields
4. Change the status to send.

Will that work?  Is there a preferred way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These steps 1-4 suggest that your PDF meta-data is not exactly what you want to have in the envelope.
In theory, if it was set right on the PDF itself, you can just do a single API call to create an envelope with this PDF and send it and you'll be done.
The reason you need steps 2-3 is to modify the fields per your requirement, and yes this can work. Even PDFs that don't have form fields can be sent and you can add the tags using anchor strings or fixed positioning as needed.